# Android: FirebaseUser, AuthCredential and others not found after Android Studio upgrade to 2.2 with com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0

Tags: android, firebase, upgrade, firebase-authentication, android-studio-2.2

I just upgraded Android Studio to version 2.2, I'm on the stable channel.

I then adjusted the build.grade file by bumping the version of `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:x.x.x'` to `9.4.0`, which is currently the latest version.

After syncing the project I am no longer able to use

`import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;`

`import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;` and

`import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;`

The online docs for Firebase don't mention anything related to this issue.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently New Version Released

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1    Analytics
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1    Realtime Database
com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1 Storage
com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1   Crash Reporting
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1    Authentication
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1   Cloud Messaging and Notifications
com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1  Remote Config
com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.1 Invites and Dynamic Links
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1 AdMob
com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1 App Indexing
```

I Hope This May Heplfull !!

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info. I mistakenly said that I increased the version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth`, but that was not true (my bad), I had increased `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth` to 9.6.1. But the Online docs mentioned 9.4.0 for Firebase as if it were the current one. It's working now

Answer (score 1):

First of all latest version is not 9.4.0 it's **9.6.1**  secondly. I would suggest you to do a clean - rebuild.

I would suggest you to **check if you are really using latest version of gradle , all plugins and then do clean - rebuild** also try **file - invalidate cache and restart.**

This should probably solve the issue. Do let me know if this info was helpful.

Comment: Yes, thanks, the issue is now solved. Nikunj Paradva was a bit quicker...