# cannot resolve symbol FirebaseUser

Tags: android

I am just starting to work with firebase backend applications and i have an issue that says cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseUser' when i try to import it in to my project with:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
```

I have looked in to stackoverflow topics that are similar to this and most say to check my gradle compile lines which i did and they are all up to date.

here is my gradle build file (maybe i am missing something)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ljubisa.myfirstfirebaseapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: P.S. the project is synced with firebase and i have a firebase  realtime database and authentication requirements already set up online.

Comment: solved thanks to this post [resolving a graddle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748193/android-firebaseuser-authcredential-and-others-not-found-after-android-studio#_=_)